# New Process Builder disables Chatter Feed

Tags: lookup, activities, process-builder

We implemented a workflow rule with the new process builder and that disabled our chatter feed.  If we deactivate the process, the feed turns back on, and if we turn the process back on, the feed update stops.  So there's a clear connection.  Any ideas on how to fix this?

Here are some details.  The process implemented is very simple: On the activity object, whenever a new activity is created, it copies the [task].WhoId field into a custom Lookup field that's on the activity object.  That way, every activity has a pointer back to it's parent element (Contacts in this case) that can be referenced by a report (we use this for reporting purposes).  We're using the new process builder, because one couldn't do this fun stuff with old workflow rules.

As for the chatter feed, when the process is activated, whenever a new chatter feed item is inputted, the chatter feed is not updated and it just says: "Success! Record has been successfully created." But it doesn't show in the chatter feed, it only shows in related list Acitivity history.  Further, if you deactivate the process, items that were created while the rule was on, don't appear in the chatter feed, but new ones (while the rule is off) will start to post to the feed again.  (Almost as if there's a Chatter feed data object on the back-end that isn't getting the reference pointer copied over...)

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: Have you got the reason or workaround for this?

Comment: just posted latest info have on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chased this down with salesforce support 6-8 months ago, and this is a known issue:

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008XjeAAE